# Why is the Sokol spacesuit considered inadequate for EVA?

Tags: spacesuits, eva, sokol-spacesuit

According to the [Wikipedia article on the Sokol spacesuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokol_space_suit),

> The Sokol space suit (Russian: Cокол, Falcon) is a type of Russian space suit, worn by all who fly on the Soyuz spacecraft. It was introduced in 1973 and is still used as of 2013. **The Sokol is described by its makers as a rescue suit, and it is not capable of being used outside the spacecraft in a spacewalk or extra-vehicular activity**. Instead, its purpose is to keep the wearer alive in the event of an accidental depressurisation of the spacecraft.

[image]

<sup>The KV-2 variant of the Sokol space suit.</sup>

What about the suit makes it not usable during EVA? Would wearing the suit during EVA mean instant death, or would it just mean increased risk?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The suit does not contain its own life support system.  It is ventilated from a blower or, in case of a decompression, pressurized bottles within the spacecraft.  It also does not have any meteoroid protection, and it tends to balloon when pressurized, restricting movement.